# How do I store objects in the store (ngrx, ngxs) that have methods

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I understand that the Redux pattern requires only plain object to be stored in the Store (this is logical and understandable).
However, in the application I would like to use objects that have some functionality, eg methods such as: "hasParent", "isReadonly", "isValid", which are calculated.

Although, for example, ngrx does not prohibit the storing of such objects, this can lead to many problems

How should I deal with this objects storing problem?
I have two ideas:
A)
-before I save the object to the store, I serialize the object into plain data
-when reading from the store, I map plain data to the object (using the mapper or "manually" (with object constructor and setters))
B)
I resign from using class / objects, I use only plain data and I move the hasParent, isReadonly, isValid methods to the helpers / services.

None of these solutions is free from disadvantages :(. But which solution seems to be better?
Maybe there are other ways to deal with the above problem?

Comment: What is the disadvantage you see to moving those methods to a utilities service?

Comment: Can you just store the list of necessary methods and add them upon object retrieve? Or even better: having some utils service

Comment: @Will Alexander The disadvantage of the utility service is that everywhere where I want to use this object (eg. User), I have to provide (by injection) the utility service. The utility service can not use static methods because it is used in templates

Comment: @Artem, it looks like my A) solution

Answer (score 3):

How do I store objects in the store (ngrx, ngxs) that have methods
--> you don't! You store a state in the store. Functions don't belong to a state. (You seem to understand this in the question details, but I want to point this out again)

As for the functions you need:

- readonly: in most cases this is a boolean flag on the object. So I
  don't know why you want to use it as a function. If read only is
  depending e.g. on the user role or other outside factors, move it
  into a "utility function" and don't store it with the store state.
  You want to keep keep the state as small as possible.
- isValid: why would you store invalid data inside the store, which is then potentially used by another component? Personally I would consider data inside the store always as valid, but maybe there is a use case.
- hasParent: I see this more as "parentId", from which you can get the actual parent object with a helper method. But without knowing your structure I cannot say.

Before thinking to much about it, ask yourself: Do I really need a store for this. Wouldn't a service be enough. A store is the hottest things right now, but most applications don't need it! Don't use it just because everyone is talking about it!

Comment: The mentioned functions are just examples, the point is that the data from the server is raw data and often need to be processed further. For example, the isValid function may indicate whether, for example, a given User has all the necessary data or maybe the data is incomplete.
This type of function can be more, eg. getName () as the concat of lastname and firstname. Or even better, depending on the locale, the order of lastname and firstname can be different.

Comment: Agree, in this case you might not even store the complete object in the store. The calculation isValid etc can then still be done in the component, where you use the data.

Comment: I am sure that I need a store, I have used the store (ngrx) in two quite big applications and from the beginning I have had the above doubts (previously I used solutions A) which I was not quite sure if this is correct.
I see, you rather suggest not to use "fat" objects created by mapper (on retriving from store)  but just some helpers.
Thanks for suggestion